# Cardinality of the p-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am failing to find a proof for the statement that the p-adic integers have cardinality continuum.

Neal Koblitz's book says that one can find a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $[0,1]$ and then notes that his "bijection" is in fact not injective, which is not really helpful.

The provided function is given by $a_0+a_1p+\cdots\mapsto \frac{a_0}{p}+\frac{a_1}{p^2}+\cdots$. Is there a quick way to use this function to prove that $|\mathbb{Z}_p|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

Comment: Associate to the $p$-adic integer the sequence of the coefficients $a_i.$ There are $p$ choices for each $a_i.$ How many such sequences are there?

Comment: I see, there are $p^{\aleph_0}$ sequences like that. As $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}\leq p^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$, I am done. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you please be specific about which book you are reading from, and where this statement appears?  I have a copy of *$p$-adic Numbers, *p*-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions* by Koblitz.  In that text, the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is exercise 5 at the end of Ch 1 (p 19).  A partial solution is given at the end of the text (p 134-5), in which Koblitz writes "$f$ is not quite one-to-one, since a real number in $(0,1)$ with a terminating expansion has two preimages; for example $f(1) = f(-p) = 1/p$."  You might think about the cardinality of such numbers.

Comment: I am reading from that book, and referring to exactly that exercise. I hoped to avoid thinking of that cardinality with another strategy. I like Chris Leary's argument much more, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Erik Barinaga -  Your argument looks fine. You can streamline things a bit. For any finite cardinal $n,$ $2^{ℵ_0} = n^{ℵ_0} = \mathfrak{c}.$

Answer (score 1):

This function is at least surjective, hence $|\mathbb Z_p|\ge |\mathbb R|$. And the function $a_0+a_1p+\cdots\mapsto \frac{a_0}{(2p)} + \frac{a_1}{(2p)^2} + \cdots$ is injective, hence $|\mathbb Z_p|\ge|\mathbb R|$.